# How to make footer appear at the bottom of page even if no data is present?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

How to make footer appear at bottom even when no data is present in SSRS? In one of my reports footer is appearing immediate next to the last table row. It should always appear at the bottom of every page whether data is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this on your css:

```
.footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: This is not about css. Its SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS) for report generating.